# PostgreSQL-based shopping cart with easy database-level integration

Tags: linux, web-apps, ecommerce, postgresql

I am looking for a shopping cart which is easy to integrate using triggers and other database-level procedures into other applications.  The other applications are PostgreSQL-only.

Absolutely required features are:

- Must run on PostgreSQL
- Must have an easy-to-understand database scheme with database operations that lend themselves well to trigger-based integration solutions (whether direct replication of data or using a solution like pgq or pg_message_queue).
- Must run on Linux.
- If doesn't support shipping, must be relatively easy to modify to support shipping
- Must be easy to add support for a given payment gateway.

Really "nice to have" features are:

- Free/open source
- Shipping integration